# WPF MVVM Light dynamic list source on data grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

Okay, I have an admin screen in my application.  Originally, the plan was to have a datagrid for each Entity and we would hide/show them.  I believe there is a better way to do this with ONE data grid.  That way, I do not need to make Add/Edit buttons for each datagrid (you can't have the same name) which leads to a mess of codes and re-writing things that I feel can be made dynamic.  SO, I created a custom class called AdminDataGrid:

```
public class AdminDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public AdminDataGrid()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "UpdateDataGrid", (action) => UpdateDataGrid(action));
        Messenger.Default.Register<ICollectionView>(this, "ReceiveDriverList", (x) => this.CurrentItemsSource = x);
    }


    public void UpdateDataGrid(string model)
    {
        switch (model)
        {
            case "Driver":
                Messenger.Default.Send<string>("GetDriversList", "GetDriversList");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    #region INPC

    public ICollectionView CurrentItemsSource { get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(CurrentItemsSourceProperty); } set { SetValue(CurrentItemsSourceProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentItemsSource", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(AdminDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion
}
```

My test case with the driver list is working for setting the variable.  The idea is that I am using the current VMs and not having to inject all the different services in to this Admin view model.  Here is the XAML:

```
<localData:AdminDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItemsSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                         SelectionMode="Single" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                         SelectionUnit="FullRow" x:Name="LookupsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

I know something is wrong with this code because when I select the 'Driver' option from my menu of Entities it does NOT load the datagrid with the list.  The AdminDataGrid class is in a utilities folder I created as a separate class.

Once I can populate the datagrid with whatever I wish, I will then run some logic in the code to customize which columns I show.  So for the moment, my main problem is:  Why is the datagrid not updating when the ItemsSource changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this binding .

```
 <localData:AdminDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self} , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Your CurrentItemsSource property is in the same DataGrid so you need to bind it to Self RelativeSource

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe that was all I needed.  Thank you SO much.